# SSAS Cube, restrict access by aplication

Tags: ssas, olap, olap-cube, windows-firewall

Is there a way how to restrict access to SSAS Cube by application?

I would like to have access only from "my application" and restrict all other application, like Excel.

Maybe add some special key in to connection string and then deny all connections without it on windows firewall? (but I can't find if this is possible, its just an idea)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

n-tier architecture

Client Apps <== HTTP WS ==> Server Apps <=> SSAS
access to SSAS - only on the local network (from Server Apps).

The client application accesses the Server only through web-services